# Laravel 7 - contains ever return false

Tags: php, laravel

i have a collection , where i do this

```
$food = $items->where('name','sandwich');
```

after this , i have a object collect empty .

```
$foods = collect([]);
```

so , i iterate over my obj to push inside foods , like this :

```
foreach ($food as $f) {
            $foods->push($f->attributes);
        };
```

so , when i do a return $foods , i receive .

```
[{meal: 1}, {meal: 1, rice: 1}]
0: {meal: 1}
1: {meal: 1, rice: 1}
```

but , now when i do this :

```
$b = $foods->contains('meal',1);
```

return me 'null' .

Comment: Did you mean `$b = $foods->contains('meal',1);` ? (forgot the **s**)

Comment: sorry , was foods , i have edited.

Comment: `Collection::contains()` shouldn't return `null` in any case.

Comment: Your example code works for me btw: https://web.tinkerwell.app/#/snippets/31e9c99b-19e2-4786-ac81-7b07b1bb9769

Comment: its so funny , but Bazaim was right , was just a 's' , sorry guys